# how to detect which option is selected in inline query results telegram bot api

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a shopping telegram bot that is written by [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk).

I already enabled inline Query features via `/setinline` command in  **@botFather** for my Bot.

I handled that how can I show some reault to user like this picture : 
[image]

And suppose this is my Codes :

```
$inlineQuery = $update->getInlineQuery();

$query = $inlineQuery->getQuery();

$results = array();
$results[] = array(
    'type' => 'article',
    'id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Query: ' . $query,
    //'input_message_content' => array(
        'message_text' => 'Text',
    //),
    'description' => 'description',
);

$params = array(
    'inline_query_id' => $inlineQuery->getId(),
    'results' => $results,
);

$result = $telegram->answerInlineQuery($params);
```

But I do not know how can I detect which options is tapped by user.

For example I want when user rapped on an option get the `product_id` uniti then can fetch details of that from database.

Comment: Can you use javascript ?

Comment: I know JavaScript but why that? I'm working on laravel and php

Comment: Because you can play with data written by you customers !

Comment: How ? please explain more

Comment: use ajax to send your data to your db and fetch what you need,  i don't know well this framework so....

Comment: @Robin I think your comments are completely unrelated to what the question asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [callback feedback](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#collecting-feedback).

> To know which of the provided results your users are sending to their chat partners, send [@Botfather](https://t.me/BotFather) the `/setinlinefeedback` command.
>   With this enabled, you will receive updates on the results chosen by your users.

Comment: yes, I enabled `Inline feedback' and set it to 0.1%. but after that i do not receive any update. even I do not know format of update message in this case

Comment: You can set to `ENABLE` which means 100% during testing